# NGINX UTF-8 encoding

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, nginx, utf-8

I have a LDAP installed on Ubuntu 14.04. 
My webpage is UTF-8 but I have problems when retrieving data from a form. When I submit a form that contains characters like 'ñ' or 'é' and I print the $_POST var the data I submited is corrupted because of a encoding mismatch as I undersand.

I have read a lot of tutorials and I have done everything I have found. 
This is how looks my** **nginx.conf**** now:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;


events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {
        charset utf-8; <----    This should be the fix     --->

        .... other things
```

Should I modify de sites-enabled/default also? ( It doesn't change the result anyway )

This is the** **headers**,** from wget -S

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
  Date: Thu, 31 Jul 2014 16:41:36 GMT
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Connection: keep-alive
  X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.3
```

The only way around for making it work was setting **accept-charset="ISO-8859-1" in the form tag**, but this is not a solution because doesn't work in IE and my web is a little more than a form.

Comment: Show the result `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_Name LIKE 'character_%' OR Variable_Name LIKE 'collation%';`

Comment: @Rhim But the error appears before I insert the string to the database. It is bad encoded in the post variable already

Comment: Sorry, did not understand the problem, repeat your settings, the problem is not reproduced, resultat `UTF-81Array ( [nombre] => República [next] => Submit Query ) 1`  `nginx version: nginx/1.6.0; PHP 5.3.3`

Comment: @Rhim I have changed in the form to accept-charset="ISO-8859-1" and now it works in Chrome but not in IE. Anyway, I would like a full solution, this is like a hack, and I have too many forms to hack. Also if I change the header charset to ISO-8859-1, the page doesn't displays well because it's UTF-8. Where I go now?

Comment: this are the headers my pages sends:HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
  Date: Thu, 31 Jul 2014 15:43:52 GMT
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Connection: keep-alive

Comment: I think that here a more detailed [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542107/please-help-me-trace-how-charsets-are-handled-every-step-of-the-way)

Comment: Thanks for the reading, but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @Rhim I am an expert at this time about encoding ;) but I still stuck.  I have double checked that my page is UTF-8 and my server is also UTF-8.

Comment: This is a problem the client (browser), but yet I could not repeat the problem, windows 7 (IE, Firefox) and Linux(Firefox).